ECharts set grid height to zero
Is it possible to set grid height to zero? See this demo, even if I set grid.height to 0, the chart still shows.
The effect I want is to hide the chart, including the line and the axis, but keep everything else (including the dataZoom) and not leave an empty space there. Is that possible?
To be more specific, what I want is the dataZoom component, but not the  way it works now. So I figure maybe I can just hide the chart and keep the dataZoom and listen to the dataZoom change event.

Additionally to setting the grid height to 0 you could make the series for this grid transparent:
Example:
series: [
  {
     ...
     silent: false,
     symbol: 'none',
     lineStyle: {color: 'transparent'}
  }
]


If you can translate your "zoomable data" to a category axis, it is enough to set the axis show property to false.
Example:
option = {
  grid: {height: 0},
  xAxis: {
     type: 'category',
     show: false,
     data: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
  },
  dataZoom: {},
  yAxis: {
     type: 'value',
     show: false,
  },
};

